# Shopify - Date now not updating on page refreshes

Tags: shopify, liquid

I've noticed that if I use:

`{{ 'now' | date: "%S" }}` in my liquid code - on refreshing the page that outputs it, the seconds shown does not update.

Are there some inner workings of how that is displayed that I need to be aware of?

Any ideas why this could be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify caches responses and it's a bit unclear how often it's updated. You should rely on js to work time instead of liquid ;)